# jsp and javascript communication

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
function dropdown
{
    if(x==1)
    {
        <%String unit="apple;%>
    }

    else if(x==1)
    {
        <%String unit="orange";%>
    }

    connection to db.......
}
```

is my code.......only the last loop gets executed.... based on unit...i need to connect to database.....can any one guide me

Comment: Scriptlets... JS connecting to database? Feels like needles in my eyes... early in the morning.

Comment: I don't even see a loop in your code...

Comment: Excessive ellipsis just makes you appear stoned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The browser makes a request
2. The webserver runs the JSP
3. The webserver delivers an HTTP resource to the browser
4. The browser parses the HTML and executes any JS in it

JavaScript control statements (like `if` and `else`) won't stop JSP code from executing (JS `is` and `else` just mean "Print this text to the browser" as far as JSP is concerned). At this stage, it is too late to send data to the JSP program as it has finished executing.

You need to make a new HTTP request to get data back to it.

You probably want to use Ajax for this, but do [build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build) (i.e. have a normal form submission). [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) provides a convenient abstraction layer.